# Longest Path A*, Admissible Heuristics, and Optimality

Tags: algorithm, a-star, heuristics

I'm working on a modified A-Star algorithm.  It tries to find the highest-weighted path instead of attempting to find the shortest path.

I have some number of classes, each with a list of unique nodes.  Each node has its own value. I'm attempting to determine the best possible combination of nodes from each class to determine the combination or path having the greatest weight. To do this, I am viewing these classes as a tree, with each level containing the nodes in a single class.

Then I search through this tree using A-Star or more specifically, im searching through my tree based on a search stack.  Once a node is explored, its children are inserted in a sorted order based on their weight (plus their ancestors weight) plus the possible future weight (my heuristic).  Then the top of the stack, with the highest value is selected to search next.

To do this I have an overestimating heuristic; it never underestimates the optimal solution.

If I am looking for the highest weight and not the lowest weight, is this heuristic admissible, and thus is my algorithm optimal?

I should also say my algorithm is currently working, and it is working much faster than brute forcing all possible paths, I'm just wondering if my solution is optimal.

PS: A FormalIsh defination of the current algorithm.

Let S = {S<sub>1</sub>, S<sub>2</sub>, ... , S<sub>n</sub>}

and each S<sub>i</sub> has a set of items and a NULL, which represents an item not chosen from this set.

S<sub>i</sub> = {I<sub>1</sub>, I<sub>2</sub>, ... , I<sub>m</sub>, NULL}

Also each item only ever exists in one set, IE S<sub>i</sub> U S<sub>j</sub> = S<sub>i</sub> + S<sub>j</sub>

Each Item, I<sub>i</sub> has an associated value, V<sub>i</sub>.

The problem is to select a maximum of M offers, one from each set, when summed yield the highest value. I call this selection a Path, P<sub>i</sub>.  A path can be complete, meaning it has a selection from all S, or it can be partial where only x offers are contained within it.  Also M

In addition, there exists a function IsCompatable(path) that returns true if a path is compatible. Whether a path is compatible or  is completely arbitrary.  The Max valued path must be compatible.  This is why I can not trivially select the M largest Items from each set.

In addition each set contains a NULL item, so that an item need not be selected from that set.

The Trivial Algorithm would to make a search tree and generate all possible combinations of items in S, with each path to the trees leaves said to be a path.

let G(P) be the current value (the summed value of each item) of the partial path.
Let H(P) be an estimation (heuristic) of the value of the future path. 
H(P) = The Y values from Y items from Y S<sub>i</sub> in S. Each item is the item with the maximum value in the S<sub>i</sub> where i > len(P). Y = M - the current length of the partial path P.

To Find the path with the greatest value, I keep a sorted Queue of partial paths, sorted on their values + their possible future values, ie G(P<sub>i</sub>) + H(P<sub>i</sub>).  I Initialize this Queue by adding paths contained in S<sub>1</sub>.

```
While the Queue is not empty or a path has not been found:
    p = Pop the path from the top of Q
    if p is Complete:
        A full path has been found
        return p
    find the possible children of p by adding an item to p from the next set.
    for child in Children:
        if IsCompatable(child):
            add child back to Q in sorted order on G(child) + H(child)
```

There it is, now is my Heuristic admissible?

### Problem description

(This has been added on in an attempt to formalize the problem description.  It is incomplete.)

Consider a set U, partitioned into disjoint subsets S<sub>1</sub>, ..., S<sub>n</sub>.

Let f : U → ℝ be a function that assigns a value to each item in U.

Let V be the set of all subsets of U containing at most one item from each S<sub>i</sub>, and let V' ⊂ V be the set of permissible solutions.  Membership in V' can be easily computed.

The goal is to find the solution P ∈ V' which maximizes ∑<sub>x∈P</sub> f(x).

Comment: A tree has a single path between each pair of vertices, I am not sure what exactly are you after, every path from `u` to `v` is both shortest and longest path.

Comment: Also, if you want to find the longest path (to any target) overall from  a given source, in a tree, a simple BFS will do.

Comment: Yes that is my null case.  I know I can generate all possible paths, and sort them by weight, to find the longest path.  But that would involve generating and sorting about 700,000 paths.  I am trying to use this heuristic to search for the best path smarter.

Comment: I've attempted to formalize the description.  It is clear that this is NOT a search problem, but rather it is an optimization problem.  Question: using my notation, given X ⊆ Y, does Y ∈ V' imply X ∈ V'?  Or, put another way, does removing items from a valid path always produce another valid path?  Or are there known rules for how items can be removed from a valid path to produce another valid path?  The description seems somewhat ambiguous on this note.  I'd like to reiterate my recommendation for branch & bound, in either case.

Comment: >Or, put another way, does removing items from a valid path always produce another valid path?

Yes.  I dont see how B&B would help me, since i could branch to a path that results in an invalid path or i can prune the best path since the best path would have a lower value than other, invalid paths.

Comment: Also my algorithm works, im just wondering if my heuristic is probably optimal.

Answer (score 1):

A* is not designed for this.  Such a heuristic would not work because you must reject loops (otherwise there is no solution), and the heuristic would always underestimate the distance from a given node if there were no path to the target that did not create a loop... but there is no way to know this.

There is no known good general way to solve this problem, because longest-path problem is NP-hard, as shown by reduction from the Hamiltonian path problem (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem#NP-hardness)).

Comment: As I said, since my data structure of nodes is a tree, no cycles or loops exist

Comment: @hoshi: Then why are you using A* in the first place?  You should probably be using Minimax or some other decision algorithm.

Comment: Because it finds the best path(s) in a sorted order, which I need.  Also because sets of nodes that span the different classes which they are in, are said to be incompatible. Thus making a decision at any point in a tree may yield an incompatible set of nodes, yielding a worse result than if the decision was not made at all

Comment: @hoshi: Sorry, I meant to suggest branch & bound.  You might want to specify your problem a little more clearly: you are asking for algorithmic advice, so it would help to use the language of mathematics to express your question; but your question is expressed using the language of computer programming, which makes it more difficult to figure out exactly what you are talking about.

Comment: Ill Update my post to make it more formal.